# how to develop wordpress site in 2 languages?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Tell me please how to develop a WordPress site in 2 or more languages. I have tried some plugins (qTranslate plugin, ZdMultiLang plugin) but is not what i want.

Comment: I recommend you to use WPML, i've used it many times and it works well

Answer (score 0):

You can localize themes and plugins quite easily, you need to read about internationalization (I18n). WordPress codex explains it pretty well: http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers.

Any HTML text in your theme files should be output with the i18n functions, this will make the string translatable. For example:

`<p>Some text here</p>`

should be:

`<p><?php _e("Some text here", "textdomain"); ?></p>`

You can later translate this exact string with a POT file, see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#POT_files

I can't stress how important it is to read the codex on internationalization - it can explain it better than I ever can.

Comment: cane someone help me with the last WPML plugin ?